# How can I subclass UISegmentedControl having custom designated initializer?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Seems like a trivial issue but I am not able to make this compile.
Neither in playgrounds nor in normal swift ios projects. 
(Please note I am not using Storyboards that's why I don't need / care about the init?(coder) part..it;s jsut it has to be include otherwise the complier complains about it.)

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {    
   let configuration: [String]
   required init(configuration: [String]) {     
        self.configuration = configuration            
        super.init(items: configuration)
    }    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}
let x = SegmentedControl(configuration: ["a","b"])
```

It is complaining about not having the deisignated initializer implemented.

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class
>   '__lldb_expr_167.SegmentedControl'

I don't understand what is going on here. Isn't the designated initializer the init(items:) for UISegmentedControl? I am calling it in my subclass designated initializer.

Comment: It compiles fine for me. (Note, I edited your question and took out the blank lines. Also, I moved the `let x...` into `viewDidLoad`. Did I edit something wrong? (I don't use playground, but it works fine in a new project.)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    var configuration = [String]()
    required init(configuration: [String]) {
        super.init(items: configuration)
        self.configuration = configuration
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}
let x = SegmentedControl(configuration: ["a","b"])
```